Re-Scaling Embedded Images?
Is there a way to rescale embedded images? I can't really control the size of screenshots that I take.
The post that caused my issue: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4999632/1447838

On [meta.se]: Resizing an image in a post?
On this meta: Can we manually adjust image width in a post? and Rescaling images after posting. And also: Scaling down large images in posts.

@MartinSleziak Thank you. That's what I was looking for. Didn't think to check main Meta.
